# Bones wont deform mesh in real time

Tags: bones

It happened after I saved a pose to a pose library, when I move the bones, I have to click again to see the mesh deformed. I can't figure out how to get it to move in real time without clicking again. This is in 2.77.

Comment: Your question is to vague to find a clear answer to your problem. you should give us more information (gifs/screenshots) and or upload your blendfile. But my first guess is, that you might accidentally hit the "Delay Refresh" Button. It can be found under "Properties->Armature->Display->Delay Refresh".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, silly me somehow toggled "delay refresh", i didn't know about that feature it until Demon's Fate pointed it out.